# Move column without changing the reference

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel sheet were you paste data into from another program. There are twenty or so columns and I want to find and move eight of them all the way to the left but when doing so the references to them changes. Even if I add dollar signs.

This is the code that moves them:

```
For i = 1 To lastColumn
    If S.Cells(1, i) = "Status" Then
        S.Columns(i).Cut
        S.Columns(1).Insert
        Exit For
    End If
Next i

For i = 1 To lastColumn
    If S.Cells(1, i) = "Order" Then
        S.Columns(i).Cut
        S.Columns(2).Insert
        Exit For
    End If
Next i

For i = 1 To lastColumn
    If S.Cells(1, i) = "Delivery" Then
        S.Columns(i).Cut
        S.Columns(3).Insert
        Exit For
    End If
Next i

For i = 1 To lastColumn
    If S.Cells(1, i) = "Deliverymethod" Then
        S.Columns(i).Cut
        S.Columns(4).Insert
        Exit For
    End If
Next i

For i = 1 To lastColumn
    If S.Cells(1, i) = "Deliverypriority" Then
        S.Columns(i).Cut
        S.Columns(5).Insert
        Exit For
    End If
Next i

For i = 1 To lastColumn
    If S.Cells(1, i) = "Usertype" Then
        S.Columns(i).Cut
        S.Columns(6).Insert
        Exit For
    End If
Next i

For i = 1 To lastColumn
    If S.Cells(1, i) = "Article" Then
        S.Columns(i).Cut
        S.Columns(7).Insert
        Exit For
    End If
Next i

For i = 1 To lastColumn
    If S.Cells(1, i) = "Shelf" Then
        S.Columns(i).Cut
        S.Columns(8).Insert
        Exit For
    End If
Next i
```

In another sheet I have several formulas referencing to these columns. Example:
`=COUNTIF(S!$H:$H;"*")-1`

When I run my code, the columns moves to where they should but the formula changes to
`=COUNTIF(S!$I:$I;"*")-1`

Is there a way to move the columns without changing the reference?

Comment: If you need the initial references, you should write (in code) again the formulas as you want them... When you move columns, Excel automatically adapt the reference to the moved range in its actual position.

Comment: Copy values from original column and then paste these values to target column. Clear original column.

Comment: Thanks for the answers! I actually went with FaneDurus suggestion. Wrote the formulas in the code. Was a bit of work bur now it works as it should!